# Colouring non-contiguous blocks of cells quickly

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have an application that generates a (quite large) spreadsheet containing user output that needs to be color coded. As I generate the data I find the blocks that need to be colored, but coloring them is time consuming if I do it one block at a time. What I'd like to do is maintain a large non-contiguous group of cells and color it using one Excel Interop call.

Right now I'm maintaining a range for each color, and every time I find a new block needing that color, I take the union of the the existing range and the new block. Then at the end I color that range. Unfortunately this is really slow and kind of buggy for large cases. Is there a better method of doing this? I feel like coloring a few thousand cells shouldn't take this long. :)

**Edit**
The following code solved it with conditional formatting (assuming the words CORRECT and INCORRECT are present in column B)

```
With newSheet.Range("B:B")
    .FormatConditions.Add(Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlCellValue, Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlEqual, "CORRECT")
    .FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 4

    .FormatConditions.Add(Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlCellValue, Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlEqual, "INCORRECT")
    .FormatConditions(2).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End With
```

The only thing I'd still like to do is color more than just the cell containing "CORRECT". Instead I'd like to colour the whole row in the chart (e.g. if B42 contains "CORRECT", I'd like A42:H42 (the row containing it) to be green). Any tips for doing that?

Comment: Can you use conditional formatting in your situation ?

Comment: I can understand why setting cells one at a time is slow, but why would setting the color of a Union/multi-range be slow?  Are you re-composing the multi-range as part of every coloring operation?  (sure would help to see some code here).

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply - I only have access to the code when I'm at work. I think conditional formatting will solve the problem, I'll report back as soon as I've tested it. Otherwise I'll post some code to explain the problem more - basically it isn't the setting color that is slow, it is building the union (for every new non-contiguous block it needs a call like newRange = Union(oldRange,newBlock))

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur Conditional formatting worked, thank you. There is still one thing I can't get working and that is colouring a few cells in the same row as the one I'm checking the condition for (see the edit to my question). If you know how to do that, please let me know. Also, if you want to add your suggestion as an answer rather than a comment, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional formatting.

As for the colouring cells in the same row, you would need to use formula conditional formatting. For example, if you want columns A, C and D to be conditionally formatted on the value in E you can do something like this (pseudo-code):

for columns A, C and D of the current row
    set conditional formatting to formula : predicate based on column $E and current row

This would most probably translate into something like:

```
=IF($Erow=something, 1, 0)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822801.aspx

Also, originally when suggesting conditional formatting I was talking about manually doing it. Is there a reason why you need to use VBA for this task ?

Comment: Thanks again for the help. The reason I'm doing it in VBA is that this application will be used by people besides me (and using different data sets than I am using), and it makes things seem a lot less polished if I tell my users they have to manually colour the spreadsheet to make it easy to read. :)